# JBPM6 How to display work flow chart in web page

Tags: jbpm

I have no idea to display the workflow chart in web page? How to display the workflow chart

Comment: What do you mean with workflow chart? The process definition (editable or read-only)?  The process instances (annotated with runtime data)?  Are you using the jBPM console (aka workbench) or want to embed it in your own application?

Comment: Thanks for you  response,I Wanna to embed that jbpm6 to my maven application,But I was confused how many artifactId should i added to pom.xml,and how to embed jbpm-workflow to my maven project.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JBPM6 API instead of Kie Rest services:

- Generate PNG image of your process from Kie Workbench designer.
- In your application, get the PNG image from kjar using Class.getResourceAsStream.

`getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("processFileName-image.png");`

Comment: Thanks,aabadia.Could you please give me some sample for display jbpm.png to web page!Thanks!